# Windows 11 on 16 core processor reduces CPU utilization when minimizing python processing console window - WHY?

Tags: windows, powershell, cpu, python, process

I have a weird issue when doing long term image processing on my 16 core 24 thread i7 13700k processor, on windows 11 pro. My processing lasts for hours so I fire up several python scripts in PowerShell consoles at the same time to utilize all the cores. However, when I minimize a console, the scheduler decides to reduce CPU utilization e.g. from 60% to 30%. Why is it doing that? I dont need and dont want that! All foreground applications are still fast since I still have cores left do do other work on.

I have done some research but all I find is options to reduce background processing to "speed up" your computer. Thats silly when you have 24 logical processors - and I am looking for the reverse!

Setting high priority on the processes in task manager doesnt work at all.

Also, maybe minimizing a windows does not make it a background process. Then again, why does W11 reduce the CPU utilization of a minimized process that obviously needs a lot of CPU power to do its job, while at the same time idling CPU cores?

There was another, similar, question asked a while ago but not answered. So I decided to ask it again.

Finally - yes I can keep the windows maximized. But its easy to forget that minimizing increases your processing job by two fold, not utilizing your hardware to the fullest as you would expect.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: I don't have a lot or repetition with python with powershell, but curious if coding python for high priority logic wise would help, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023038/change-process-priority-in-python-cross-platform and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060383/lowering-process-priority-of-multiprocessing-pool-on-windows you may be able to reverse those or use parameters and values to make high priority. Task Scheduler and running from there may help. Seeing how you execute the python with PS may help as well as seeing Python code but those are quick things for thought perhaps.

Comment: I wonder if this is at all to do with P cores and E cores in that CPU - something to research I guess

Comment: Thanks @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle for the suggestion. I will look into it. And yes maybe also the notion of P and E cores with the new W11 scheduler could be a factor. I wonder if someone can reproduce this on a similar platform.